# Google compute engine UDP service only accessible from external IPs

Tags: google-compute-engine, udp, ipc

I have a small and simple UDP server that's been working in several hosting places for years.

I just created a new vm in the google cloud, a Compute Engine, with linux.

Default settings for a small machine (f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)
CPU platform Intel Sandy Bridge), with only changes:

- static public IP
- inbound firewall rule to allow UDP traffic at the server port (22000)

Everything works great and can be connected from anywhere in the world, **except** from the machine itself (there's a stats module that asks the server for info - this also work from remote, but not from the machine itself). This worked in all other linux machines I tried the server on.

I was pointed at changing the address the server binds to as a possible solution, and as I have access to the source code I tried all I can imagine to no effect (binding to 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, "localhost", specific IP...).

I have also tried adding a specific inbound *and* outbound firewall rules.

There are tons of information around about how to fix when you cannot connect from outside - my problem is the opposite, and I'm of ideas.

Ping etc work normally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the server configured to listen? How is the client configured to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Apparently in these machines / kernel UDP sockets need to have a name (bind) **before** sending - never needed in other machines I installed the server.

Not a server administration thing - it just seemed as if it could be.